# Read an .csv and export it to a brand new csv file - PowerShell

Tags: powershell, csv

I'm brand new using powershell, and need some help. I have a csv named test.csv and looks like this:

```
----------------------------------
name         lastname       alias        
John         Smith          John              
Marie        Curie          Mary
----------------------------------
```

The thing is that i need to export the info of the two rows into two different files. The name of the file should be the one that is under the 'alias' column

Example:

```
Name: John

-----------------------------------
name         lastname       alias        
John         Smith          John

-----------------------------------

Mary

----------------------------------
name         lastname       alias        
Marie        Curie          Mary

----------------------------------
```

I tried with the following script:

```
Import-Csv c:\test\test.csv  | foreach ($line ){New-Item c:\test\$_alias.csv -type file}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

This script ought to work for you. It creates a new file for each line, using the `alias` field as the file name.

```
$Data = Import-Csv -Path c:\test\test.csv;

foreach ($Item in $Data) {
    Export-Csv -InputObject $Item -NoTypeInformation -Path ('c:\test\{0}.csv' -f $Item.Alias);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution uses scripting loops and variables:

```
$path = "c:\test\"
$csv = Import-Csv "$($path)test.csv"
$csv |
%{
    Export-Csv -InputObject $_ -NoTypeInformation -Path "$($path)$($_.Alias).csv"
}
```